# Notification icon that looks like "b" with segmented rings and a circle

Tags: htc-one, notification-icons

I have this strange icon that appears in my notification bar (on the right hand side) every once in a while. I have only seen it when running an app in fullscreen, and then checking stuff in the notification bar. It disappears after a few seconds when quitting the full screen app.

[image: notification icon]

(I have HTC One M8 with Android 4.4.4)

Comment: Have you looked at all your installed apps to see if any of them have a similar or related looking icon?

Comment: @MichaelKohne Worth noting: "in my notification bar (**on the right hand side**)" (emphasis mine). That almost rules out an app, as the "right hand side" usually is reserved for "system status".

Comment: Checking my sources, this might be a status icon signaling "Location service is ON" (see [network icons on this page](http://cellphoneforums.net/lg/t365759-lg-g2-notification-status-bar-icons-what-they-mean.html), right column, third-to-last row). Unfortunately, each manufacturer seems to use his own set of icons, so it's hard to say. So you might try a Google Image Search on the terms "htc notification icons" (a good load of useful results, I've just tried).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [HTC BoomSound](http://www.htc.com/us/smartphones/htc-one-m8/boomsound/). It shows when sound is playing.